# how to pass data from one entity to other entity class?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services

i am getting all chapters in my chapterDC class and also getting regions, i have a property of selectedRegion in my chapterDC class and want to pass my region data into regionDC through chapterDC,but my log message is always 0 and null, i don t know what mistake i am doing

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllChapters
{
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@get_all_chapters",kWSURL];
    NSDictionary * returnDict = (NSDictionary *) [self callWebService:url];
    if([[returnDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"])
    {
        NSDictionary * responseDict = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSArray *resultArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"result"];

        for(NSDictionary *chapterDict in resultArray)
        {
            ChapterDC * chapter = [[ChapterDC alloc] init];
            chapter.ChapterDC_ChapterID=[[chapterDict objectForKey:@"ChapterID"]intValue];
            chapter.ChapterDC_ChapterName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"ChapterName"]];
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionID=[ [chapterDict objectForKey:@"RegionID"]intValue];
             NSLog(@"%d",chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionID);
            chapter.ChapterDC_AddressLine1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"AddressLine1"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_AddressLine2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"AddressLine2"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_AddressLine3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"AddressLine3"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_Email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"Email"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"URL"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_FacebookURL =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"FacebookURL"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_LinkedInURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"LinkedInURL"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_PhoneNumber =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_Postcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"Postcode"]];
            chapter.ChapterDC_TwitterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [chapterDict objectForKey:@"TwitterURL"]];

            NSDictionary * regionDict = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"region"];

            {
            chapter.selectedRegion = [[RegionDC alloc] init];
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionID = [[regionDict objectForKey:@"RegionID"]intValue];
            NSLog(@"%d",chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionID);
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [regionDict objectForKey:@"RegionName"]];
                NSLog(@"%@",chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_RegionName);
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_ContactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [regionDict objectForKey:@"ContactName"]];
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_Mobile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [regionDict objectForKey:@"Mobile"]];
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_Landline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [regionDict objectForKey:@"Landline"]];
            chapter.selectedRegion.RegionDC_TrainingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [regionDict objectForKey:@"TrainingURL"]];
            }
            [returnArray addObject:chapter];
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should encapsulate the int within an NSNumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace  `NSDictionary * regionDict = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"region"];`
with

```
NSDictionary * regionDict = (NSDictionary *) [chapterDict objectForKey:@"region"];
```